# How to add files from local disk to zip archieve in laravel

Tags: laravel, php-ziparchive

I want to add files from local disk to zip archive .
Pay attentions that my files located at storage local disk not public disk.

```
            $filesAddress=Answer::where('questionid',$questionId)
                            ->pluck('answer')
                            ->all();
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        foreach ($filesAddress as $fileAddress){
            if($fileAddress!==''){
                $relativeName=explode('/',$fileAddress)[3];
                $file=Storage::disk('local')->get($fileAddress);
                $zip->addFile($file,$relativeName);}

        }
        $zip->close();
        $headers = array('Content-Type'=>'application/octet-stream',);
        $zip_name =time()."_$questionId".".zip"; // Zip name
        return response()->download($zip_name,$headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found how to add files where exist in local disk storage in laravel.

```
            $filesAddress=Answer::where('questionid',$questionId)
                            ->pluck('answer')
                            ->all();
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $zip_name =time()."_$questionId".".zip"; // Zip name
        if ($zip->open(public_path($zip_name), ZipArchive::CREATE)|ZipArchive::OVERWRITE){
            foreach ($filesAddress as $file) {
                $relativeNameInZipFile = explode('/',$file)[3];
                $zip->addFile(Storage::path($file), $relativeNameInZipFile);
            }
            $zip->close();
        return response()->download(public_path($zip_name));
```